# Radio button issue in react hook form with bootstrap radio button group

Tags: bootstrap-5, react-hook-form

I am trying to add a radio button in a react hook form and the code looks as follows..

```
import { Controller, SubmitHandler, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

interface Values = {
  myBoolean: boolean;
}
 

const Form = ({ values }: { values: Values }) => {
  
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    watch,
  } = useForm<Values>({
    defaultValues: {
      myBoolean: values.myBoolean,
    },
  });

  const processForm: SubmitHandler<Values> = async (data) => {
    console.log('data', data);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(processForm)}>
      <Controller
        name='myBoolean'
        control={control}
        render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value, ref } }) => (
          <div 
            className='btn-toolbar'
            role='toolbar'
          >
            <div className='btn-group btn-group-sm' role='group'>
              <input
                type='radio'
                className='btn-check'
                onBlur={onBlur}
                onChange={() => onChange(true)}
                checked={value === true}
                ref={ref}
              />
              <label className='btn btn-outline-secondary'>Yes</label>
              <input
                type='radio'
                className='btn-check'
                onBlur={onBlur}
                onChange={() => onChange(false)}
                checked={value === false}
                ref={ref}
              />
              <label className='btn btn-outline-secondary'>No</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      />
      <button
        className='btn btn-primary'
        type='submit'
      >
        Save
      </button>
    </form>
  )  
}

export default Form;
```

I get the button toolbar rendered with the initial Yes checked but then clicking on the No button does nothing. If I remove all bootstrap css it works ok but it doesn't like the button group. ny ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, finally got this working, I was missing a unique ID on my input and then a for attribute on my label. e.g. <input id='button1'.../> <label htmlFor='button1' .../> Stupid!